# HTML templating with vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, templating

I'm having a SharePoint app that retrieve page content from a library, and feeding both desktop and mobile sites. We also have links within the page, how can I render HTML templating with vanilla JavaScript?

For example, we have couple on-page links from the page content:

`<a class="template" href="/3.aspx">`

I want to add either `http://<sitename>/pages/` or `http://<sitename>/pages/m/` infront of the href depends on the screen size or devices.

How can I achieve that via vanilla JS ?

Comment: Device or screen size ?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ it can be either.

Comment: Desktop small sized window==mobile ?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ they won't be able to access desktop site if they use a mobile devices due to backend setting. So if they use mobile devices, they can only access mobile site. I'm just wondering how to swap out the href if that's something possible.

Answer (score 2):

With a lightweight library called [lit-html](https://polymer.github.io/lit-html) it's straightforward:

```
import { html, render } from 'https://unpkg.com/lit-html/lit-html.js?module';

const linkTemplate = orientation =>
  html`<a href="https://<sitename>/pages/{orientation != null ? 'm/' : '/'}3.aspx">Link text</a>`

render(linkTemplate(window.orientation), container)
```

Answer (score 1):

Screen size way:

```
function isMobile() {
    return window.innerWidth < 800;
}

var mobileUrl = 'http://<sitename>/pages/m/1.html';
var desktopUrl = 'http://<sitename>/pages/index.html';
window.location = isMobile() ? mobileUrl : desktopUrl;
```

More elegant "duck type" mobile check

```
function isMobile() {
    return typeof window.orientation !== 'undefined';
}
```

Also there is a way to analyze `navigator.userAgent` value

Comment: This is great! I guess my confusion is where to use the variable mobileUrl and desktopUrl  in HTML. I try to avoid adding templating framework such as mustacheJS or HandlebarsJS into my site. Is there a way I can use vanilla JS to achieve that as well?

Comment: For example, I'd want to add <a href={{mobileUrl}}/5.aspx> into my HTML and render the {{mobileUrl}} by using vanilla JS